# Coach platform positions for trains in Austria

Tags: short-connections, austria, train-stations, salzburg

We'll be travelling in coach 10 of the EC 219 to Salzburg Hbf, Platform 9 and need to change to another train departing from Platform 4.  We don't have much time and will probably need to use the elevators.  To reduce the chance of missing the connection, we want to plan things in advance to be as efficient as possible.

I found [a map of Salzburg Hbf](https://www.oebb.at/dam/jcr:e33e2ad7-6a8b-48fe-be62-55ca6b38c94d/karte-lageplan-salzburg-hbf.pdf) showing the position of the platforms and elevators.  Is there any way of finding out in advance which coach number of our train is likely to stop next to the elevator?  This way we could wait by that coach's door shortly before our train arrives.

In Austrian stations there is usually a *[Wagenreihungsanzeiger](http://imageshack.com/i/poadW2Alj)* that shows, for every train, which coaches stop at which parts of the platform.  Is this information also available online somewhere?  Or failing that, is this something that I could find out in advance by writing to OEBB customer service, or by asking the staff in the train itself?

Comment: I'm not aware that it is available online, but writing the customer service can't harm. ... But: If the connection time is so small that walking to the elevator is a problem, it's pretty risky in any case. The trains often are not that much on time either.

Comment: Missing the connection due to a train delay is not so catastrophic, financially speaking, because that entitles us to take the next available onward train. But missing the connection due to a queue at the elevator is less defensible, and we might be asked to buy a new ticket.

Comment: From what I understand, the lifts and escalators are close to the middle of the platform, so moving close to the middle of the train should be the best option. Slightly forward if you prefer the lift or stairs, slightly back if you prefer the escalators. Incredibly modern station for one that is in the middle of a city...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your mobility (physical, amount and weight of luggage) it may be that the faster way is to use the stairs (Some platforms have escalators). Salzburg Hauptbahnhof is not that big and every platform is accessed from the underground "hub". Waiting for the lift may cost you more time and they are not that big, so it is entirely possible that the elevators will be full and you have to wait for the next one.

Secondly, if you are really tight on time, don't bother finding the right coach. Just board any coach and walk through the train until you find the one you have reserved seats. (or just use empty seats if they are more convenient to you). Once you have boarded the train, you can always ask a train conductor to point you in the right direction.

Edit:

As it seems I have misinterpreted your reason for asking about the locations of the coaches relative to the platform, let me repeat: Salzburg Hauptbahnhof is not that big. You can go from one end of the train on the platform to the other in about a minute, if you pace up your strides. There are two stairs on each platform which means you will have to go a maximum of about half of the length of the train to reach them.

Comment: I believe the point of the OP was not to find the right place to board the second train, but the right place to disembark from the first train to be as close as possible to the elevators (or stairs).

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Measured by Google Maps, the platforms are 400+ meters long. To walk that in one minute, you need to _really_ pace those strides...

Comment: There are no half measures...

Comment: The biggest potential bottleneck here is not our walking speed but the queue at the elevator. If there are too many people ahead of us waiting to use it, then we may miss our connection. This is why I want to be as close as possible to it when the train stops.  If I knew for certain that we would instead be able to take the stairs or the escalator, then I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: I always use the stairs. If you aren't carrying a shipping container with you, I recommend you do the same. How much time do you have before your connecting train departs?

Comment: I concede that my 1min remark is utterly exaggerated, but in all practicality fits: if you take into account that no train ever will be that long and come to a halt with its middle sections by the lift/stairs (of which there's two, a few dozen meters apart), you can reach the stairs fairly quickly.